# Server to server communication in Websphere / JSP

Tags: jsp, websphere

i'm sorry if this is a bit silly. I'm not even new to JSP/WebSphere. I'm working remotely with a company whose servers run this "environment" as they called it.

I need their server to send a POST request directly to my server (whitout client side intervention). My server will answer with a JSON obj that should get saved in their databases.

The person in charge of this is only able to write jsp pages. And I wonder, is it possible to do waht I need?

If you could point me to some guides with information about this, I would appreciate it. We are kinda running out of time here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with two JSps on the remote company's server and with one JSP on your server,,
lets name them as follows,,

> Remote company's JSP: **sendReq.jsp and saveJSON.jsp**
>
> Your side JSP: **sendRes.jsp**

In the ***sendReq.jsp***, code to send a POSt request using the HttpConnection class
In the ***sendRes.jsp***, code to make the JSON and send as response to saveJSON.jsp
In the ***saveJSON.jsp***, code to get the JSON from the server and store to database,

Was this helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Only JSPs on their side, but no client intervention seems like 2 conflicting requirements. They could, of course, write a bunch of scriplet code to do anything in a JSP, but JSPs don't get executed until a view needs to be rendered. i.e. a client requests it.

I guess you could get around that by having something external hit the URL of their JSP, which then in turns hits the URL of your JSON-providing service. You'd could schedule that initial URL request with something like cron.